# MYSQL, return first and last row in a JOIN in single row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is a catalog of items and the other contains a history of those items.

I would like to return values of the earliest and latest history rows within a time period joined with the items table to have one row per item that contains those two mentioned values.

Table structure is as follows:

```
items
-----
item_id, item_title

hist
-------
hist_id, hist_item_id (corresponds to items.item_id), hist_value, hist_time (stores Unix timestamp)
```

I have created an SQL fiddle with some example data to aid you, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c78363/3

As an end result I'd like to see rows like this returned, which using the example data in my fiddle would be for a time period between 1420291000 and 1420294000:

```
items.item_id   items.item_title   history_earliest   history_latest
1               ABC                1                  5
2               XYZ                1                  9
```

At present I am running a query on items to return me all items then iterating through those results in PHP and then running two queries to give me the earliest value and then another for the latest value so I am sure there are huge efficiency savings to be made but I don't have a clue where to begin!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to grab all of the values within your time range, of course you would then only need the first and last values. You could do that in code, or you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX to do this.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c78363/41

```
SELECT
  items.item_id,
  items.item_title,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hist.hist_value ORDER BY hist.hist_id ASC), ',', 1) AS earliest,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(hist.hist_value ORDER BY hist.hist_id DESC), ',', 1) AS latest
FROM hist
INNER JOIN items ON hist.hist_item_id = items.item_id
WHERE hist.hist_time BETWEEN 1420291000 AND 1420294000
GROUP BY hist.hist_item_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subqueries for that. It's not the only possible solution, but it's probably the easier to understand (and hence to maintain).

Select all fields from the `items` table, and for each item perform a subquery to find the value of the earliest history entry in the given range and another to find the latest history entry in the same range.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c78363/21)

```
SELECT 
   items.*
 ,(SELECT hist_value 
   FROM hist
   WHERE hist.hist_item_id = items.item_id
     AND hist.hist_time BETWEEN 1420291000 AND 1420294000
   ORDER BY hist_time ASC LIMIT 1
   ) history_earliest
 ,(SELECT hist_value 
   FROM hist
   WHERE hist.hist_item_id = items.item_id
     AND hist.hist_time BETWEEN 1420291000 AND 1420294000
   ORDER BY hist_time DESC LIMIT 1
   ) history_latest
FROM items
```

Comment: Thank you, this yields the result I am looking for.

Comment: I think this the same as the MAX/MIN  solution. Except this requires more processing?  Or what am I missing?

Comment: MIN/MAX using the value column, to return what I need is not useful in this situation - if I have understood how it works correct - because the value can go up as well as down. Therefore MIN not be the earliest value and MAX might not be the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I know there already is an answer but please find an alternative way - maybe somehow could help (**[SQL Fiddle with UPDATED query and results](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c78363/26)**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
  items.*, 
  _hist_e_l.history_earliest, 
  _hist_e_l.history_latest
FROM 
  items
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      A.hist_item_id, 
      B.hist_value AS history_earliest, 
      C.hist_value AS history_latest
    FROM
      (SELECT hist.hist_item_id, MIN(hist.hist_time) AS history_earliest_time,
       MAX(hist.hist_time) AS history_latest_time
       FROM hist
       WHERE 
          hist.hist_time >= 1420291000 AND hist.hist_time<= 1420294000
       GROUP BY hist.hist_item_id
      ) AS A
      INNER JOIN hist AS B
        ON A.hist_item_id = B.hist_item_id
           AND A.history_earliest_time = B.hist_time
      INNER JOIN hist AS C
        ON A.hist_item_id = C.hist_item_id
           AND A.history_latest_time = C.hist_time
  ) AS _hist_e_l
    ON items.item_id = _hist_e_l.hist_item_id
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. However, beware of ranges of time with no entries. In my solution (with subqueries), if there are no history entries for a given product in the given time range, the result would have NULL values in the `history_earliest` and `history_latest` columns. In your solution, the item in question would not appear at all in the results since no match would be found in the `INNER JOIN`s. This could be changed by using `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion - you were right. I've updated the query to solve this problem. Thx again.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT item_id, item_title, MIN(hist_TIME), MAX(hist_time) 
FROM (items JOIN hist ON items.item_id = hist.hist_item_id)
GROUP BY item_id, item_title;
```

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you are attempting to create two datasets and put them in one data-set?  That kind-of defies data-set logic (stuff SQL is based on)

You can put in subqueries in the above sql to get counts where x=y.  That maybe be performance expensive on a database

Comment: This does not achieve the desired output. What I am trying to achieve is getting two hist_value returned in one row for each row in the items, within a defined time period. What you have given above just gives me the earliest timestamp and latest timestamp.

Comment: Adjusting your query, this gives the desired output. However I am unfamiliar with MIN and MAX - I presume this is doing to return the lowest value for hist_value and the highest value for hist_value within the returned results or is this just based on the order of results? It is possible the latest value is lower than the earliest. This yields the correct ouput. SELECT item_id, item_title, MIN(hist_value) , MAX(hist_value) FROM (items JOIN hist ON items.item_id = hist.hist_item_id) WHERE hist.hist_time >= 1420291000 AND hist.hist_time<= 1420294000 GROUP BY item_id

Comment: @user887515 `MIN(hist_value)` returns the minimum value in the `hist_value` field; it has nothing to do with the `hist_time` field. So it will not produce the result you need unless the values are always nondecreasing in time.

Comment: Sorry I should have included the 'WHERE' clause.  Which you have done. MIN and MAX are called 'aggregate' functions and work only with 'GROUP BY' clause.  It is effect saying give me all fields listed by name, and some calculated stuff for the 'groups' they represent.  Another aggregate would be 'COUNT()'  if you use that it make make more clear what is going on hear.